# Does somebody knows how to register BoostrapVue with Vue in Sails WebApplication schema?

Tags: sails.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using default temps of sails web applications. But right now i want to use BootstrapVue Library inside the app. I'm finding how and where to tell to Vue to use BootstrapVue library